# Receive "must point to an installed version of node" when trying to upgrade

Tags: node.js, nvm

When trying to upgrade my Node version using either

```
nvm install v10.15.0 --reinstall-packages-from=8.9.4
```

or

```
nvm install lts/* --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

I receive the following error:

```
If --reinstall-packages-from is provided, it must point to an installed version of node.
```

I also tried changing `=node` to a path that points to where I have installed node, e.g., `/usr/local/bin/node`.

I have also tried not using the NVM method, and using the instructions provided [here](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm), but I receive the following:

```
WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/n-3eb27508/.github' /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging
WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/n-3eb27508/bin'
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this by simply downloading a new version of the OSX installer from the Node JS website and overwriting the previous version!

Comment: nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=12.13.0 didn't work, so I went and downloaded 12.13.1 and overwrote 12.13.0, but still,  nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=12.13.1 gives the error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because I had installed Node directly from the installer at the Node.js website, and the first time I tried to update it with `npm`, I got a permissions error, and was pointed to a solution to use `nvm`. So in my case, I think the error was because nvm was unaware of my previous installation of Node. Ended up just completely deleting node, npm and related files from my Mac (as per [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x?rq=1)) and just doing `nvm install node`